# Transition probabilities of a pure death process with exponential lifetime

Tags: markov-chains, poisson-process

> **Problem:** The lifetimes of elements of a certain type are independent and exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda > 0$. At time $t= 0$ there are $X_0=n$ living elements present. Let $X_t$ denote the number alive at time $t$. Show that $\{X_t\}$ is a Markov process and calculate its transition probabilities.

Let $X_t = n-Y_t$, $Y_t$ be the number of elements that died, I think $Y_t$ is a Poisson process, but I'm not sure. If it is, the rate must then depend on the state. For example if there are $n$ elements alive, the rate is $n \lambda$, but then I'm stuck, how do I find the transition probabilities?

Comment: Suppose $0\leq s\leq t$ and $n\geq k_1 \geq k_2$. To compute $\mathbb{P}(X_t=k_2|X_s=k_1)$ you should note that $k_1-k_2$ individuals passed in the span of $t-s$ units of time. Using the memoryless property of the exponential distribution, you can say the probability that an individual passes on the time interval $[s,t)$ is $\int_0^{t-s}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathrm{d}x$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: So is  $Y_t$ not a Poisson process? As each element passes independently, is it $\mathbb{P}(X_t = k_2|X_s=k_1)={k_1\choose k_1-k_2} (\int _0^{t-s} \lambda e^{-\lambda x} dx)^{k_1-k_2}$?

Comment: If exactly $k_1-k_2$ individual die then $k_2$ individuals survive. You're missing this component in your formula.

Comment: If you fix this you'll see that $$X_t|X_s\sim \text{Binom}\left(X_s,\int_{t-s}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda x}\mathrm{d}x\right)$$

Comment: Also, the possible values of a Poisson random variable are $\{0,1,2,...\}$. In your problem there can only be at most $n$ individuals that die, so $Y_t$ cannot be Poisson as the possible values for $Y_t$ are $\{0,1,...,n\}$.

Comment: I see, you are absolutely right. Thank you.

Comment: Can I ask one more question. I try to find the infinitesimal generator $Q$ of this process. 
$$
\begin{align}
p'_{ij}(t) &= ({i \choose j}(F^{i-j}(t)(1-F(t))^j)'\\ 
&= {i \choose j}[(i-j)F^{i-j-1}(t)f(t)(1-F(t))^j+jF^{i-j}(t)(1-F(t))^{j-1}(-f(t))],
\end{align}
$$
where $F(t)$ and $f(t)$ are the cdf and pdf of the exponential distribution, respectively. But then $q_{ij} = p'_{ij}(0) = 0$, where did I get it wrong? Thanks in advance.